# What are all the `KEY` specifications in MariaDB table?

Tags: sql, mariadb, key

I came across a MariaDB, and some tables created in this way (I have a full dump):

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `another_table_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_field` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `another_field` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `another_table_id` (`another_table_id`),
  KEY `ix_mytable_date_create` (`date_create`),
  KEY `ix_mytable_closed` (`closed`),
  CONSTRAINT `mytable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`another_table_id`) REFERENCES `another_table` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12924 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

There are well known `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`, but what are those `KEY` lines?
According to docs, `PRIMARY` keyword is not mandatory, so they should all be primary keys...
I noticed for all of them an index is created.
If I examine CONSTRAINTS (I'm using dbeaver) though, only `id` is present as primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just plain indexes. I'm not sure what document you looked at that made you think `PRIMARY` was optional but if you look [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#index-definitions) you'll see a syntax section:

```
index_definition:
    {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
  | {FULLTEXT|SPATIAL} [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...) reference_definition
```

Where we can see `{INDEX|KEY}`, described below as:

> `INDEX` and `KEY` are synonyms.
>
> Index names are optional, if not specified an automatic name will be
> assigned. Index name are needed to drop indexes and appear in error
> messages when a constraint is violated.

---

> so they should all be primary keys...

Except the whole concept of primary keys is about selecting one unique key for each table and declaring that key as "more special" than any other such key. You can only have one primary key per table.

Comment: Thanks, and I know very well there is ONE primary key, I was pointing out the apparent "mistake".
I've been misguided in the very same document, this part `PRIMARY KEY Column Option
Use PRIMARY KEY (or just KEY) to make a column a primary key. ` 
and also here `<cut>  [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]` but it was the column definition, my mistake.